# How to properly error trap read in c to get byte number from a file descriptor

Tags: c, buffer, file-descriptor, buffer-overflow, low-level-io

I am currently writing a small dummy program to try and get the hang of properly using the read in c. I made a small function called readdata to read from the file descriptor and store in a buffer then return the number of bytes read. My problem is I am trying to correctly error handle and trap things so that there is no buffer overflow but I keep doing something from.

Here is the tester:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 10

int readdata(int fd, char *buf, int bsize);

int main(void) {
   char buf[BUFSIZE];
   int returnval;
   int length;
   returnval = readdata(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZE);
   printf("%s",buf);
   length = strlen(buf);
   fprintf(stderr,"The return value is %d\n", returnval);
   fprintf(stderr,"The string is %s\n",buf);
   fprintf(stderr,"The length of the string is %d\n",length);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the small function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readdata(int fd, char *buf, int bufsize){
   int n = 0;
   if(fd < 0){
     return 1;
   }

   while((n=read(fd,buf,(bufsize-1)))>0){
      if(n == -1) {
         perror( "Read failed" );
         return 1;
      }
      else{
         buf[bufsize] = 0;
         return n;
      }
   }
}
```

If I run

```
 cc -o test test.c readdata.c
```

And then put

```
echo "Hello" | ./test
```

It works fine. But if I pass the bufsize limit like this:

```
echo "1234567891" | ./getdatatest
```

It gives me this weird output where it says "the string is 123456789[some weird symbol]" . So I am not sure where to handle this error or why it is still incorrectly putting in the buffer when reading.

Comment: `buf[bufsize] = 0;` invokes undefined behaviour

Comment: `read` and friends are usually used to read binary data, not text files.

Comment: to start, `read()` is prototyped in unistd.h, which the posted code did not #include.  Therefore, at best the compiler will assume all the parameters and the return type are `int`.   Suggest inserting, at the top of the file containing `readdata()` the line: `#include <unistd.h>`  then correct the call to `read()` to use the proper parameter and return types.  To help you, the prototype is: `ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);`  which strongly hints the `readdata()` function should be returning a `ssize_t` rather than an `int`

Comment: if there is a read() error <returns -1> then the loop is not entered, so the  code block `if(n==-1)` will never be entered.   Note: why return `1` when the read failed?  that `1` will be seen by the caller as indicating one byte was read.  Strongly suggest, on error, return -1 so caller is informed of the error.   `read()` can return a `0` on two conditions. 1) when trying to read from a file that already at EOF and 2) when a signal is received.  I.E. the code is not doing the right logic.

Comment: line: `buf[bufsize] = 0;` is writing past the end of the caller's buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.   Also, a 0 (in memory as :0x00000000 (in a 32 bit architecture) is not a NUL byte of '\0'.  Suggest replacing the `= 0` with `= '\0'`

Comment: while the `implicit conversion` feature will correct some of the problems with the posted code not using the correct variable/parameter/return types,  it is much better to use the correct types and not depend on the compiler to fix your sloppy coding

Answer (score 1):

You do know that `read()` can return less characters than you requested? Also, `buf[bufsize]` is just past the end of `buf`. Your `readdata` function should also return something like `-1` on error instead of `1` so you can distinguish the condition “one byte read” from “IO error.”

Consider something like this:

```
for (;;) {
    n = read(fd, buf, (bufsize - 1));

    if(n == -1) {
       perror( "Read failed" );
       return -1;
    } else {
       buf[n] = 0;
       return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: the while() loop is checking/exiting if the returned value is <=0,, so the `if` code block will never be entered.  I.E. this answer leaves a LOT to be desired

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for your remark. I improved the answer a little bit.